# Restrict access to web directory using acl

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, acl, setfacl

The requirement is to allow a specific user (e.g. someuser) full access to a directory (e.g. /var/www/html/someproject) via SSH/SFTP, but not allow browsing anywhere else.

Is it possible using only ACL?

---

I tried setting ACL like this:

```
setfacl -m u:someuser:--- /*  # no access to directories under root
setfacl -m u:someuser:x /var
setfacl -m u:someuser:x /var/www
setfacl -m u:someuser:x /var/www/html
setfacl -R -m u:someuser:rwx /var/www/html/someproject
```

But then SFTP would fail to connect with error:

```
Cannot initialize SFTP protocol. Is the host running an SFTP server?
```

Allowing access to some of the directories under root (e.g. /etc) fixes this, but then browsing in these directories would be allowed.

Comment: Do you have to use `ACL`? Because you can restrict access to other directories by configuring `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: error tells you sftp is not configured. did you see any lines with sftp  in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` ?